# How do I read .jlog containing json strings in Python using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json strings in .jlog file and want to read this file as a df containing columns using python.

My code below:

```
   import pandas as pd
   df_weblogs=pd.read_json('C:/Users/me/my_file.jlog', orient='columns')
```

It gives me an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4085b33a005e> in <module>()
----> 1 df_weblogs=pd.read_json('C:/Users/me/my_file.jlog', orient='columns')
      2 df_weblogs.head(5)

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression)
    414         keep_default_dates=keep_default_dates, numpy=numpy,
    415         precise_float=precise_float, date_unit=date_unit, encoding=encoding,
--> 416         lines=lines, chunksize=chunksize, compression=compression,
    417     )
    418 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression)
    464 
    465         data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
--> 466         self.data = self._preprocess_data(data)
    467 
    468     def _preprocess_data(self, data):

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in _preprocess_data(self, data)
    475         """
    476         if hasattr(data, 'read') and not self.chunksize:
--> 477             data = data.read()
    478         if not hasattr(data, 'read') and self.chunksize:
    479             data = StringIO(data)

MemoryError:
```

How should it be properly read?

Comment: Please give us the full stack-trace.

Comment: I added the full-stack trace.

Comment: What does the jlog file look like? can you add a sample?